# Implement a Boolean function using an 8x1 deMUX

Tags: multiplexer

Using a 1x8 deMUX with an AND gate, create F(x,y,z) where F has minterms at 1,3 and 5

This is the solution I came up with:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this solution works, but it doesn't quite fit the specifications. Can anyone help me do this with only one AND gate?

**EDIT**

Here is my function table

[image]

Comment: please show your output truth table :)

Comment: @tcrosley I'm using a 1x8 deMUX. The selects should choose an output to have the value of the data input.

Comment: @AlexanderSabiona It is uploaded now

Comment: @tcrosley they take in xyz as inputs, the xyz also goes to the data inputs

Answer (score 2):

Maybe everyone's over thinking this (or I'm missing something).

I don't think you need the logic going into D, just tie D to 1.  Then, route M1, M3, and M5 into the OR gate whose output is F.  The output will be 1 for just the correct entries of x,y and z, and 0 otherwise (i.e. 111 will have a 0 output since M7 is not fed into the OR gate).

So that's how to do it with one OR gate.  Not sure about AND ...

Answer (score 1):

Heya :) I doubt you can do this with a single AND gate only. Are you allowed to use inverted AND (NAND) gates? if so, then try converting that OR into a NAND.